# If $f$ and $\overline{f^2}$ are differentiable complex functions, can $f$ have more than one value?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-integration

> If $f$ and $\overline{f^2}$ are differentiable complex functions, can $f$ have more than one value?

I can't even find any 'fancy' $f$ such that $f$ and $\overline{f^2}$ are differentiable complex functions. On the other hand, if we take $f=const$ or $f=i\cdot const$ so $f$ is differentiable everywhere but this function always has one value.

I was thinking of finding out by Cauchy-Riemann equations like this:

$$f(z)=u(x,y)+i \cdot v(x,y)$$
$$\overline{{f^2(z)}}=u^2(x,y)-v^2(x,y)-2i\cdot u(x,y) \cdot v(x,y)$$
$$\text{Let} \quad a(x,y)=u^2(x,y)-v^2(x,y)\quad \text{and}\quad b(x,y)=-2\cdot u(x,y) \cdot v(x,y)$$
By Cauchy-Riemann equations we have 
$$\begin{cases}
a_x=2uu_x-2vv_x \\
b_y=-2(u_y+v_y) \\
a_y=2uu_y-2vv_y \\
b_x=-2(u_x+v_x)
\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}
uu_x-vv_x=-(u_y+v_y) \\
u_x+v_x=uu_y-vv_y
\end{cases}$$

And here I stoped for a while. Even wolframalpha cannot solve this system. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Differentiable I assume you mean having complex derivative, instead of the standard meaning having a differential. If $f$ has complex derivative then so does $f^2$. If $\overline{f^2}$ also has complex derivative also does $f^2\overline{f^2}=|f^4|$.

Comment: But the image of $|f^4|$ is inside the real line. By the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)) $f^4$ is constant.

Comment: The above is the argument if we know that they have complex derivative at all points in their domain being an open connected set. You can have have $f$ defined only in two disjoint open ball taking two different constants.

Comment: Thank you very much @SphericalTriangle it really helped!

Comment: So, as I understand, $f$ cannot have more than one value? @SphericalTriangle

Comment: If $f^4$ is constant, then $f$ can only take the values of the four $4$-th roots of that constant. But since $f$ is continuous, **and if the domain is connected**, then it can only take one of those $4$ $4$-th roots.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have enough reputation points to comment, but I am very curious from what book is this problem, @Karagum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f$ holomorphic $\implies f^2$ holomorphic $\implies \Re(f^2) =\frac{f^2 +\bar{f^2}}2$ holomorphic. But holomorphic and real implies *locally* constant. Using C-R equations, $\Im(f^2)$ is locally constant...

Comment: So it means that $f$ cannot have more than one value?

Comment: @Karagum, quote of SphericalTriangle: "... since $f$ is continuous, **and if the domain is connected**..." then $f$ will take only one value. But if the domain is, for example, the plane minus one straight line, $f$ can take different (constant) values in each side of the line.